# Fail to change multiple sprite mecanim state using C# scripts

Tags: c#

[image]
[image]

Above is the attachment of my mecanim state, hierarchy and folder in Animator.

The problem I'm facing now is fail to change multiple sprite mecanim state using C# script. When I move my sprite, I can successfully change it from idle to backwalk state, however it limit my changes solely to backwalk state but not all other states. I want to make it like when I press right arrow key it change to rightwalk state, while press left arrow key to change it to leftwalk state and so on. Unfortunately the if else statement that I declare is not working making my changing movement only stick to one state. I wonder what mistake I made, and how I can fix my code?

I'm a newbie to Unity and not familiar with C#. I just learn it from the official Unity tutorials series. I been searching for many related question regard of the problem but still I can't figure out the solution. This is the first question I ask at Game Stack Exchange, sorry if I violate any rules and please guide me through it. Appreciate anyone help sincerely.

Here I attach my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MoveSpeed = 1;
    float aspectspeedx = Screen.width / 1366;
    float aspectspeedy = Screen.height / 768;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    GameObject anim = GameObject.Find("taoist");
    anim.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float MoveSpeed = 1f;
    // change the string to your parameter     

    string characterfrontwalk = "taoist_front_walk";
    string characterbackwalk = "taoist_back_walk";
    string characterleftwalk = "taoist_left_walk";
    string characterrightwalk = "taoist_right_walk";
    /* if you want corner walk 
    string characterrightfrontwalk = "taoist_right_front_walk";
    string characterrightbackwalk = "taoist_right_back_walk";
    string characterleftfrontwalk = "taoist_left_front_walk";
    string characterleftbackwalk = "taoist_left_back_walk";
    // to use this corner setting , you must initialize yourself 

    */
    GameObject character = GameObject.Find("taoist");
    GameObject theanim = GameObject.Find("taoist");
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator>();
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterfrontwalk, true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterbackwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterleftwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterrightwalk, false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

    if (!(Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("right")) && !(Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("left")) && !(Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("right")) && !(Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("left")))
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterfrontwalk, true);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterbackwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterleftwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterrightwalk, false);

            character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterfrontwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterbackwalk, true);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterleftwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterrightwalk, false);

            character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterfrontwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterbackwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterleftwalk, true);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterrightwalk, false);

            character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterfrontwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterbackwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterleftwalk, false);
            theanim.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(characterrightwalk, true);

            character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        }

    }

}

    /* 

    // THIS CODE IS FOR CORNER MOVE , UN-MODIFIED , because im too tired to modify it sorry , you need to think yourself ;) 

    if( Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("left")){

        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", true);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
        character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

    }


    if( Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("right")){

        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", true);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
        character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

    }
    if( Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("right")){

        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", true);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
        theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
        character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
        character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

    } 
    // Un-MODIFIED corner setting , initialize yourself 
        */



}

public class LastDirection
{
    public string thelastdirection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of editing my last answer , i now really understand your problem :) , your first statement is look like this ( and its wrong ) :

[image: Wrong]

As you see , your statement **cannot go to other direction because they don't have the way** , and the **only way to go** to other statement is **through idle** .

Then , how to fix it ? its simple , you must create their way to other direction so they don't need to go idle first to go "there" ( the other direction ) :

[image: Right]

***First , sorry for bad draw because i used paint ;) .***

What i try to mean in the picture is , that **each of your statement must connect to all other statement with its own condition**  , **and not only connect to idle state** , i know it is a long job and can take an hour but you must do it if you want .

Well , goodluck in your project :) , i can sure you will meet other problem that i have too here and you can ask me how-to-fix it ;) , and i can help your project if you want :) .

EDIT :

Yesterday you upload the picture of the statement like this :

[image: wrong]

But honestly , its not what called " **connect each statement to all statement**  " , but what i was trying to mean is the statement **must connect like this** :

[image: work]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49241/discussion-on-answer-by-user6668201-fail-to-change-multiple-sprite-mecanim-state).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing my last 2 answer ,i will just create new :p .

I fixed your character move animation .

**It used new script , and new ability is added :

 - Character Moving script without vertical and horizontal**

Preview :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3T7xROtJ3A&feature=youtu.be

The animation play well except the animation it-self i think , you need to make the animation become better ;) .

How - To - Import :

1. Download the file - >  https://goo.gl/3Dt0HQ , if the link dead tell me
2. If you don't want to import inside your project , create new project as test-project so you can assure it won't destroy your current project
3. Open scene at asset , the scene is named "sceneone"

**4. Try to play it and learn the different with your current script :)**

---

In case the scene and script not imported :

1. Create empty scene
2. Create two empty object , one called " taoistmoverobject " and " taoist "
3. Put taoist object inside taoistmoverobject scene
4. Find the animator and the script then tag it as component at " taoistmoverobject "
5. ( Optional ) Put camera inside " taoistmoverobject " if you want to make camera follow when character moving

---

**That all ;) , don't forget to learn from it :)**

Comment: This should fix your problem :) , if you have any problem just ask me ;) , or if this doesn't work i will try another way

Comment: Studying it now

Comment: if it work , mark it as solve , if doesn't work , don't mark it and tell if its not work ;) , im open for question at facebook either email

Comment: Well ... im sleepy though , i will take a sleep now , i go back about .... 15 hour later . Any question just email me .

Comment: good :) , i know its hard but keep learning ;) .

Answer (score 0):

I know what problem was going on because i had the trouble with it too , the problem is at both side , **the scripting and animator** .

To make it instantly change like from left instantly to right , **you must connect / put transition between all animation with it own condition** .

Not just like from idle -> right , but also right -> left , right -> down , right -> up and ect .

**Never use vertical and horizontal method , its not work the best , just detect which button the user hold and do the movement .**

The preview is look like this  :

https://www.youtube.com/embed/rivOHgxp2Cw
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rivOHgxp2Cw

and this is the script i used for your example ;) learn how the script work and watch the preview video   .

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterMove : MonoBehaviour {
 public float MoveSpeed = 1;
 float aspectspeedx = Screen.width / 1366;
 float aspectspeedy = Screen.height / 768;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  GameObject anim = GameObject.Find("Character");
  anim.GetComponent<Animator> ();
 }
  
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  LastDirection lastdirectionvar = new LastDirection ();
  GameObject character = GameObject.Find("Character");
  GameObject theanim = GameObject.Find("Character");
  theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ();
  /*
   
   Change one of them to true
   
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   */
  /* if (!(Input.GetKey ("up") || Input.GetKey ("down") || Input.GetKey ("left") || Input.GetKey ("right"))) {
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   // if (lastdirectionvar.thelastdirection == "down") {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", true);

   // }
  } */
  if( Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("left")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

   }

  if( Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("left")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

  }


  if( Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("right")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

  }
  if( Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("right")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

  }

  if ( !(Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("right")) && !(Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("left")) && !(Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("right")) && !(Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("left")) ) {
   if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }
   if (Input.GetKey ("down")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }
   if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }
   if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }

  }

  /* if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f) {
   character.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
  }
  if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") < -0.5f ) {
   character.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (0f,Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0f));
  } 

  anim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetFloat ("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"));
  anim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetFloat ("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical")); */

 
 }
}

public class LastDirection {
  public string thelastdirection;
}
```

This is code for your character :

```js
void Update () {
        float MoveSpeed = 1f;      
              
          // change it to your object name that work as character
          
           string charactername = "taoist";
       
        // change the string to your parameter     
                   
        string characterfrontwalk = "taoist_front_walk";
        string characterbackwalk = "taoist_back_walk";
        string characterleftwalk = "taoist_left_walk";
        string characterrightwalk = "taoist_right_walk";
        /* if you want corner walk 
        string characterrightfrontwalk = "taoist_right_front_walk";
        string characterrightbackwalk = "taoist_right_back_walk";
        string characterleftfrontwalk = "taoist_left_front_walk";
        string characterleftbackwalk = "taoist_left_back_walk";
        // to use this corner setting , you must initialize yourself 
        
        */
  GameObject character = GameObject.Find(charactername);
  GameObject theanim = GameObject.Find(charactername);
  theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ();
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterfrontwalk, true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterbackwalk, false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterleftwalk, false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterrightwalk, false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

   }

  /* 
        
        // THIS CODE IS FOR CORNER MOVE , UN-MODIFIED , because im too tired to modify it sorry , you need to think yourself ;) 
        
        if( Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("left")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

  }


  if( Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("right")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

  }
  if( Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("right")){

   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeft", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRight", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveLeftDown", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightDown", true);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("MoveRightUp", false);
   theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("NotMoving", false);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);

  } 
        // Un-MODIFIED corner setting , initialize yourself 
            */
  if ( !(Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("right")) && !(Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("left")) && !(Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("right")) && !(Input.GetKey("down") && Input.GetKey("left")) ) {
   if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterfrontwalk, true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterbackwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterleftwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterrightwalk, false);
    
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   } 
   if (Input.GetKey ("down")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterfrontwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterbackwalk, true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterleftwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterrightwalk, false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x, character.transform.localPosition.y - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }
   if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterfrontwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterbackwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterleftwalk, true);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterrightwalk, false);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x - 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }
   if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterfrontwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterbackwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterleftwalk, false);
    theanim.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool (characterrightwalk, true);
    character.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (character.transform.localPosition.x + 0.05f * MoveSpeed, character.transform.localPosition.y, character.transform.localPosition.z);
   }

  }


 
 }
```

Comment: Seriously thanks so much for your effort and you even made a Youtube video to help me out. Very touching. I'm still trying my best to understand the code. 

I upload a picture in the question above as I can't upload it at this comment. 

Is this the correct set up of mecanim state in animator? I want to move my sprite in four direction: up, down, left, right.

Comment: its right but is the conditions right ? go click the transition and look at inspector

Comment: @ user6668201

For the condition, I set it as 
character_front_walk(state) > character_back_walk(state) using condition: backwalk = true
:::::::::::::::::::::::::
character_back_walk(state) > character_front_walk(state) using condition:
frontwalk = true

Comment: you need more condition , example like character_front_walk > character_back_walk , use backwalk = true and frontwalk = false  not only backwalk = true

Comment: can you tell me all the state and the object name that used as "character" ? i can create the script for you

Comment: I had upload my picture attachment above. In the hierarchy, I set my character name as Taoist, but in animator controller file I set the name as Player1

Comment: in statement , is it character_front_walk or taoist_front_walk ?

Comment: @6668201
 taoist_front_walk

Comment: EDITED ! that code should work :) , if the code work , please mark this answer as solution ;)

Comment: CHANGE THE STRING LIKE CHARACTERFRONTWALK CHARACTERBACKWALK TO YOUR PARAMETER

Comment: EDITING TO ADD OBJECT NAME PLS WAIT

Comment: edited , your script is completed ;)

Comment: @user3633433

I post the combination of the script you written in above code attachment . The red line problem is solved but still the character can't move and change state. Also when I hit the play button, there is yellow warning pop up at the bottom state: "The reference script of this behavior (Game Object 'Taoist') is missing.